I want to automatically populate a neighboring cell in Google Sheets to help assign document numbers
I am creating a request system for my lab that will automatically create a copy of the request form (a google document), and I ask the user to name the submitted form with an ID. The ID will look like this: ENV####, or ENV0001 for the first one. I want that ID to be in the title of each document, and this has to be done by hand.
So, I want the user to go to my database spreadsheet, enter the name of their document, and have the neighboring column automatically fill with the next code ID, so ENV0002 for example.
I know this is possible, but how do I do it?
I have looked up how to do this, but all the systems involved a whole lot more steps than I was expecting.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. How many steps are you expecting?

since you did not specify if empty rows are possible, use:
=INDEX(TEXT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A10), "\E\N\V000#"))

